# React select list from get method

Tags: reactjs, list, select, get, axios

I have a problem with React Select. I'm using axios get method to get a data to dropdown list and then i want to show it in React Select.

I copied the code from the github example, but it doest work.

Get method:

```
onListaDzial = () => {
  axios
    .get("http://10.10.10.27:81/eWizjaAPI/api/Listy/GetSlownikDzialy?", { params : {rok : this.state.rok }, headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ this.state.token }})
    .then(function (response) {
          let options = response.data.map( category => ({ value: category.text, label: category.text}));
          return { options };
}) 
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error,  }));

}
```

React select code in render

```
<Select name="form-field-name" options={options} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the state of the component in order to use it within the render function. Also you need to use a arrow function within `.then` else the this context is wrong!

```
onListaDzial = () => {
  axios
    .get("http://10.10.10.27:81/eWizjaAPI/api/Listy/GetSlownikDzialy?", { params : {rok : this.state.rok }, headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ this.state.token }})
    .then((response) => {
      let options = response.data.map( category => ({ value: category.text, label: category.text}));
      this.setState({options});
  }).catch(error => this.setState({ error,  }));
}
```

and in render

```
<Select name="form-field-name" options={this.state.options} />
```

You could also rewrite the `onListaDzial` function to async/await like following:

```js
onListaDzial = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get("http://10.10.10.27:81/eWizjaAPI/api/Listy/GetSlownikDzialy?", { params : {rok : this.state.rok }, headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ this.state.token }}).catch(error => this.setState({ error,  }));
  let options = res.data.map( category => ({ value: category.text, label: category.text}));
  this.setState({options});
}
```